# Exporting a filled up cloudformation stack template?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

I used a CF template to deploy a stack of resources on AWS. Now, I'd like to retrieve that filled up template, so I can convert it to HCL for later Terraform deployment. Where would I get that "filled up" yaml file from?

Comment: What do You mean by "filled up"? With parameters You provided before deploying it?

Comment: @ExceptionNotThrownException Yes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here You go:

1. Go to CloudFormation and pick the stack You want to get the template from:  [image: Pick stack]
2. Switch to template tab:[image: Template tab]
3. Here You go, You should see the template. Keep in mind this template can be YAML or JSON, depending on what kind of template You installed. Both should be well readable.

Comment: That changed nothing, the template is as it was uploaded.

Comment: Keep in mind You have the Parameters tab. The template references the parameters. 
You should see something like ```!Sub ${MyParameter}``` in YAML. You can exchange this with the actual MyParameter value from the parameters tab.